# Filter elements from Set basing on class

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have a abstract class AAA with subclasses BBB, CCC and DDD. Basically, I also have a hashSet of different subclasses of AAA. I need to filter that somehow to only get BBB's out of that.

Something like this:

```
var example: Set[test.AAA] = hashSet(BBB.e1, CCC.e2, BBB.e3, BBB.e4, DDD.e5)

def magicalFunction = ???

example.magicalFunction

=> example: Set[BBB] = Set(e1, e3, e4)
```

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you want?

```
sealed trait AAA;
case class BBB(tag: String) extends AAA;
case class CCC(tag: String) extends AAA;
case class DDD(tag: String) extends AAA;

val example: Set[AAA] = Set(new BBB("e1"), new CCC("e2"), new BBB("e3"), new DDD("e4"))
val onlyBBB = example.collect { case x: BBB => x } 
// Set(BBB(e1), BBB(e3))
```